# Execute query according to the result of another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

I have a query that gives output "OK".

I want to use that result from the query to run another query.

If result is OK then don't run.
If it is ERROR, then run.

The queries are slow and I don't want to execute the second query if the result is OK. The second query checks what is wrong.

How I can do this? I checked  in the Internet but I don't know if there is such function and it's name. I don't want to use nested queries or WITH expressions

Thanks!

Comment: I am trapped in the same situation ,researching on it..but  until you can use if-else,write your attempts.

Comment: did u researched for `try` and `catch` blocks, please add some sample queries. Usually second query runs depending on result set of first query, why would first query fails

Comment: @Ven my problem is something differ from it

Comment: The first query checks if the result from the two table are equal and counts them, the second query shows which records are different. The output from the first query is 'OK' or 'ERROR' and the counts. I want to use the 'OK' and  'ERROR' output as a condition to run the next query

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: If you read the descriptions for the `mysql` and `tsql` tags you'll find that they are, for most purposes, incompatible. Are you really looking for a solution that will work across multiple different databases?

Answer (score 1):

you can put result of the query into variable and then check it using [IF...ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql)

```
declare @test varchar(10) = 'ok';

if @test != 'ok'
    begin
       --query if not 'ok'
    end
else
    begin
        --query if 'ok', or you can remove `else` at all if not required
    end
```

[**DEMO**](https://rextester.com/FQIMV64265)

Answer (score 1):

Use Try and Catch to error handling and do what you want to execute as per below:

If Query 1 is executed then query 2 skip otherwise execute query 2 if any error in query 1:

```
Begin Try 
 --Query 1
End Try 
Begin Catch    
  -- Query 2
End catch
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a variable in which you store the result of a function that returns 'OK' or 'KO' ([How to create a function with SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql)).

Then you can use an IF statement where you execute different queries 
[IF statement SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql).

This could be an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Capture result set into a variable. Also ensure your condition returns one or other and only one column

I have added a sample query

```
declare @output VARCHAR(10)
SET @OUTPUT =
--sample query 
(select case when  SUM(s.SellingValue) = SUM(h.SellingValue) then 'OK' ELSE 'ERROR' END OUTPUT
from Missing_Sales s inner join Missing_Sales_TH h on s.Branch_no = h.Branch_no and s.date = h.Date)
BEGIN
IF @output = 'OK'
--sample query
SELECT * FROM Missing_Sales
ELSE 
--sample query
SELECT * FROM Missing_Sales_TH
END
```